# Get a persistant string in and out of the TPM2 module

Tags: tpm, tpm-2.0

I'm trying to save a small amount of data in the TPM2 over power cycles.  So that this small string will only be tied to one specific machine.  Here is what I have working.

```
# put data in file that is to be sealed
echo "my sealed data" > seal.dat

# create a primary key
tpm2_createprimary -c primary.ctx

# create a child key in public and private parts
tpm2_create -C primary.ctx -u obj.pub -r obj.priv

# create a sealed object
tpm2_create -C primary.ctx -i seal.dat -u obj.pub -r obj.priv

# load the private and public portions into the TPM
tpm2_load -C primary.ctx -u obj.pub -r obj.priv -c key.ctx

# unseal the data
tpm2_unseal -c key.ctx
```

But after a power cycle if I enter:
'tpm2_unseal -c key.ctx'
I get the following error:

*WARNING:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_ContextLoad.c:279:Esys_ContextLoad_Finish() Received TPM Error 
ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_ContextLoad.c:93:Esys_ContextLoad() Esys Finish ErrorCode (0x000001df) 
ERROR: Esys_ContextLoad(0x1DF) - tpm:parameter(1):integrity check failed
ERROR: Invalid item handle authorization
ERROR: Unable to run tpm2_unseal*

I am using the tpm_server (emulator) if that makes any difference.

So what is the best way to load a small string into the tpm2 and have power loss persistence?

Answer (score 1):

Sealing an object does not store anything in the TPM's NV memory. It encrypts the data with a key that's only accessible to the TPM, but it is saved in two files on your file system -- nothing is saved in the TPM.

To store some data in the TPM's memory, you would define the memory index and then save to it, for example:

```
tpm2_nvdefine -Q $nv_test_index -C o -s 32 -a "ownerread|policywrite|ownerwrite"
echo "please123abc" > nv.test_w
tpm2_nvwrite -Q $nv_test_index -C o -i nv.test_w
```

And then to read the data back:

```
tpm2_nvread -Q $nv_test_index -C o -s 32 -o 0
```

(sample code from [tpm2-tools test script](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/test/integration/tests/nv.sh))

Answer (score 0):

You forgot one command that persists the information in the TPM: *tpm2_evictcontrol*. In the example below the value is persisted to the persistent handle 0x81010001.

```
# tpm2_createprimary -Q -C o -c prim.ctx

# echo "mytestkey12345678abcdefg" | tpm2_create -Q -g sha256 -u seal.pub -r seal.priv -i- -C prim.ctx

# tpm2_load -Q -C prim.ctx -u seal.pub -r seal.priv -n seal.name -c seal.ctx

# tpm2_evictcontrol -C o -c seal.ctx 0x81010001
persistent-handle: 0x81010001
action: persisted

# tpm2_unseal -Q -c 0x81010001
mytestkey12345678abcdefg
```

The persisted value can be removed by calling

```
# tpm2_evictcontrol -C o -c 0x81010001
```

There is a nice explanation involving also PCR policies [here](https://tpm2-software.github.io/2020/04/13/Disk-Encryption.html).